# RS-150-12 AC Input Switch

Tags: power-supply, switcher

I recently bought a MAXWELL RS-150-12 switching power supply but I can't find any documentation on how to select the ac input voltage (115V or 230V).

Here is a picture of the switch: (I want to select 230V to be the input voltage)
[image]
[image: enter]

I dont know which position sets which input voltage. My guess is: the voltage that is visible on the switch is the selected one.
But I'm not sure and I dont want to damage the supply.

BTW: I only have 230V avaiable so I cannot test the setting with a lower voltage.

Comment: I'd say you're correct in guessing that what's visible is the intended input but I am not 100% sure. Are you able to see the part number on the switch? If so you could look up the data sheet and see what it says.

Comment: As said, the datasheet gives no information about this switch :S

Comment: Yeah I looked at the data sheet for the PSU and it's not clear. I meant the data sheet of the actual switch component. If it's intended to be used a certain way then it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used these Meanwell supplies.  You are correct that the visible number is the intended input.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the correct answer, a bit of background for those that might like to know how these things typically work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyTpMs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The top schematic has 230VAC RMS 50Hz input, the bottom has 115VAC 60Hz input. The only difference is that the SPST switch is closed in the below schematic to turn the circuit into a voltage doubler. RL represents the load. There would be inrush elimination, a fuse, EMI filtering and other circuitry in a real implementation, the point is that both circuits produce a +320V rail for the switching power supply to use.

If the switch is closed and 230VAC is applied, it will try to generate +640V and will kill lots of parts.

Startup simulation:

[image]

Comment: Very nice, Spehro. I learned something :)